# Adobe Native Extension Android layout xml not accessible

Tags: android, adobe, air-native-extension

Building an Native Extension for Android, I'm trying to integrate the google mapview, which works well up to the point, when I try to access properties from the layout. The errors appears in the activity-class that extends the mapview:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // <- this crashes, same for textview etc.
```

The xml, that's loaded looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"  >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textfield1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"  />

<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:apiKey="0cy94dNyuBcfF0aNZhB_JKpF4dQtxgDWhCXppRw" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_clear"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="@string/clear"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_add"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

What I've found and checked so far:

- extension is loaded correctly, as the map view in the xml layout is displayed correctly
- res-folder is copied and compiled into the ANE (unzip-checked) as well as the APK (unzip-checked)
- problem exists for all layout-elements, the app crashes on accessing the textview, too. So it's not a map-specific problem
- project works fine when run standalone, so it's got to be something concerning the extension

I've read some posts about using getRessourceId, but that would imply the need to inject the FREContext into the activity, what sounds strange to me.

Any hints really appreciated!
Thanx, M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured the first part out. You actually have a static FREContext in you activity. In your extension function set this context with the one, you get:

```
    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {

         MyActivity.freContext = context;
```

In your activity, you set the layout by it's resourceId:

```
    setContentView( freContext.getResourceId("layout.my_layout_xml"));
```

Hope this helps someone.